# Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'. [react-native wix navigation][v2]

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

After following all steps in the [official v2 documentation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/v2/#/docs/Installing) I get the following error:

```
$ cd ./android && ./gradlew app:assembleDebug && ./gradlew installDebug

> Configure project :react-native-navigation 
downloadRobolectricDependencies into /Users/michaljarnot/IdeaProjects/react-native-redux-wix-navigation/android/build/robolectric-3.5.1-dependencies

> Task :react-native-navigation:compileReactNative56DebugJavaWithJavac 
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

This is a minimal implementation of the official documentation:

1. Step: https://github.com/developer239/react-native-redux-wix-navigation/pull/3/commits/ec0e0143642c3743c1e9ff085ec1db2fd8701d91
2. Step: Skipped
3. Step: https://github.com/developer239/react-native-redux-wix-navigation/pull/3/commits/55529ecbb600e9c382ce36a19f3c1c1f529fefbb
4. Step: https://github.com/developer239/react-native-redux-wix-navigation/pull/3/commits/1fd8d3c6e011f2eac89ace24849b8029aa816b4d
5. Step: https://github.com/developer239/react-native-redux-wix-navigation/pull/3/commits/fe780338806f4b480540b9ec170d043467b08510
6. Step: https://github.com/developer239/react-native-redux-wix-navigation/pull/3/commits/0f785ab442bf71baff01e1ed9eb23899677967a7
7. Step: https://github.com/developer239/react-native-redux-wix-navigation/pull/3/commits/9b5bcfc4c0b6f55e13563377345bab92267ed7ad
8. Step: https://github.com/developer239/react-native-redux-wix-navigation/pull/3/commits/43e264da148344f609d892440ca8a012283aef93
9. Update `package.json`
   https://github.com/developer239/react-native-redux-wix-navigation/pull/3/commits/79e555cba30d83a1dad251621dcbd6d2673980b0
10. Downgrade to `react-native@0.56.0` https://github.com/developer239/react-native-redux-wix-navigation/pull/3/commits/a4e5fcdd7fcdb8d56450e6eb915995865b4fd23b

Can anyone with `android` knowledge please point me in the right direction?

Here is a link to issue on GitHub: https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/3974

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Have you implemented this `compileOptions {sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }`  in the  `android/app/build.gradle` yet ?

Comment: If it still not solved your problem, delete the android directory and then recreate it by using `react-native eject android` and start over all implementation from react-native-navigation

Comment: @STEPHENbui I will try to do that thanks :)

Comment: Oh I already implemented the sourceCompatibility here: https://github.com/developer239/react-native-redux-wix-navigation/pull/3/commits/1fd8d3c6e011f2eac89ace24849b8029aa816b4d